# List containing only every second second pair of elements

Tags: python

I am new to python and so I am experimenting a little bit, but I have a little problem now.

I have a list of *n* numbers and I want to make a new list that contains only every **second pair**  of the numbers.

So basically if I have list like this

```py
oldlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

then I want that the new list looks like this

```py
newlist = [3, 4, 7, 8]
```

I already tried the `slice()` function, but I didn't find any way to make it slice my list into pairs. Then I thought that I could use two `slice()` functions that goes by four and are moved by one, but if I merge these two new lists they won't be in the right order.

Comment: I don't see pairs in your destination list. I think your approach is correct, but you need to combine the pairs, interleaved.

Comment: If you don't have pairs, do you expect the output to contain unpaired values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [a[i]  for i in range(len(a)) if i%4 in (2,3)]

# Output: b = [3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Here, we use the idea that the 3rd,4th,7th,8th..and so on. indices leave either 2 or 3 as the remainder when divided by 4.

Comment: You may want to check out [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 16):

If you enumerate the list, you'd be taking those entries whose indices give either 2 or 3 as a remainder when divided by 4:

```
>>> [val for j, val in enumerate(old_list) if j % 4 in (2, 3)]

[3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I might suggest `if ((j // 2) % 2) == 1` where now the first `2` is the size of the grouping, the second `2` is the interval of groups, and `1` is the index to select from the interval. `if ((j // size) % interval) == index` This allows you to parameterize the group size and index. E.g. for `if ((j // 3) % 2) == 0` you can get groups sized 3, with an interval of 2 groups and take the first index, `[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]`.

Comment: @flakes big +1 to the suggestion! Can I include your suggestion in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68122252/3896008) as well?  Also, not sure if I should delete my answer because Mustafa's answer does the same thing but is more pythonic since no explicit indexing is used in this answer.

Comment: @lifezbeautiful You're free to use it!

Comment: Would `if j % 4 > 1` work as well?  I don't know Python, but it seems like it should be a simpler (and more readable) way to get the same result.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It would work but I kindly disagree on the readability part. `in` is somewhat more direct imho.

Answer (score 6):

```py
first_part = oldList[2::4] # every 4th item, starting from the 3rd item
second_part = oldList[3::4] # every 4th item starting from the 4th item

pairs = zip(first_part, second_part)
final_result = chain.from_iterable(pairs)
```

Comment: Oh and probably slap a `list(...)` around the `chain.from_iterable(pairs)`

Answer (score 3):

Break this problem in to parts.

```
first = oldlist[2::4]
second = oldlist[3::4]
pairs = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(first, second)]
```

Now unwrap the pairs:

```
newlist = [x for p in pairs for x in p]
```

Combining:

```
newlist = [z for p in [(x, y) for x, y in zip(oldlist[2::4], oldlist[3::4])] for z in p]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would firstly divide original list into two lists, with odd and even elements. Then iterate over zip of them.

```py
old = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
result = list()
part1, part2 = old[::2], old[1::2]
for i, z in enumerate(zip(part1,part2)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        result.extend(z)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a double range:

```py
oldlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
newlist = []
for i,j in zip(range(2, len(oldlist), 4), range(3, len(oldlist), 4)):
    newlist += [oldlist[i], oldlist[j]]

#> newlist: [3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: This will miss items if the two ranges end up with unequal lengths.

Comment: I would argue that effect might even be desirable, as the OP explicitely asks for **pairs**. But yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
import more_itertools
oldlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[*more_itertools.interleave(oldlist[2::4], oldlist[3::4])]
# [3, 4, 7, 8]
```

`oldlist[2::4]`, `oldlist[3::4]`: slice 4th item
`[*more_itertools.interleave(...)]`: interleave the two above and convert back to a list

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have come up with:

```
oldList = list(range(1,10))
newList = []
for i in oldList:
    if (i%2 == 0) and (i%4 != 0):
        try:
            newList.append(i+1)
            newList.append(i+2)
        except IndexError:
            break
```

Result:

```
>>> newList
[3, 4, 7, 8]
```